# DiagrammeR and MathJax do not correctly render a graph in a rmarkdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown, diagrammer

I am using the following `rmarkdown` example, which does not show the symbol `theta` nor the caption of the figure, and the first node is too wide (see below the output):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

The example is:

```{r nnet02, echo=F, fig.cap="Multilayer"}
library(DiagrammeR)

add_mathjax(
grViz("digraph G1 {
  graph [layout=neato overlap = true]     
  I1 [pos='1,1!'    style=radial label='$\\\\theta$']
  I2 [pos='2,1!'    style=radial]

  I1 -> I2
}", width = 550))
```
````

[image]

Could you please help me?

Comment: Theta is disappearing by me? By you too?

Comment: Exactly, @manro. Theta disappears.

Comment: I can offer to you next solution, one minute.

Comment: you could use [html labels](https://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/symbols.html) e.g. `label='&theta;'`. Also see the [graphviz docs](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html)

Comment: Thanks, @user20650! Unfortunately, I also need to use superscripts and subscripts.

Comment: @PaulSmith ; graphviz takes html labels so you can use `<sup>` and `<sub>`

Comment: Thanks, @user20650! I have tried `label=<&theta;<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>>`, but superscript and subscript get unfortunately misaligned.

Comment: oh yes, reminds me of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334738/improve-positioning-of-subscript-and-superscript-on-node-labels.

Comment: Thanks, @user20650! I have followed your advice and put that as an answer. Without your direction, I would have not found that workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know we can find all necessary symbols in Unicode.

(Mathjax is redundant?)

**Your modified code:**

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

The example is:

```{r nnet02, echo=F, fig.cap="Multilayer"}
library(DiagrammeR)


grViz("digraph G1 {
  graph [layout=neato overlap = true]     
  I1 [pos='1,1!'    style=radial label='\U03B8' fontsize=15]
  I2 [pos='2,1!'    style=radial fontsize=15]

  I1 -> I2
}", width = 550)
```
````

[image]

**With sups and subs:**

```
  ***
  I1 [pos='1,1!'    style=radial label=  '\U03B8\U00B3'  fontsize=10]
  I2 [pos='2,1!'    style=radial label=  '\U03B8\u2085'  fontsize=10]
  ***
```

[image]

---

**Some additional thoughts**

We can draw our graph in the viewer(with MJ).
Export as image and add after to our RMarkdown.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @manro! Can one also use subscripts and superscripts? That is also a reason because I use `mathjax`.

Comment: @PaulSmith Certainly. One moment. Ready.

Comment: @PaulSmith This resource will be useful for you: https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/superscript-and-subscript-letters/

Comment: Thanks, @manro! From your approach, I guess it is not possible to place the superscripts a bit higher and the subscripts a bit lower. Am I right?

Comment: @PaulSmith I don't know :) We can change our font and look. Wait)

Comment: @PaulSmith So, fonts didn't help. About Mathjax and disappearing. We have problem because our diagram has .SVG output. I tried to find a solution, how to embed MJ to SVG, but couldn't do it. Maybe you handle. I'll glad to see it.  F.e. ```label= <<foreignObject> ... </foreignObject>>``` don't work...

Comment: Thanks, @manro! I suspect it is an `add_mathjax`'s bug. I have meanwhile filed a bug against `Diagrammer` (in GitHub). Let us wait for feedback.

Comment: @PaulSmith Cool! But now you can look to my addition and make whilst all graph in console or in r-script ;) But surelly tell about an answer from Github later.

Comment: I have found a workaround. If you are interested, please see my above edited question.

Comment: @PaulSmith Cool, but I have added +1 to you still yesterday ;)

Comment: Thanks, @manro! Now, with that workaround, one can use graphviz with Latex equations, without any trouble!

Answer (score 1):

Following @user20650's mention of the question [Improve positioning of subscript and superscript on node labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334738/improve-positioning-of-subscript-and-superscript-on-node-labels), a workaround could be constructed:

1. Inside a `cat chunk` one writes the graphviz `dot` code, which will be subsequently saved as a `gv` file:

```
{cat, engine.opts=list(file = 'sample.gv')}
digraph G1 {
  graph [layout=neato overlap = true];
  I1 [pos="1,1!" label="\\theta^2_j"  shape="circle"];
  I2 [pos="2,1!" label="\\sum_{i=1}^n I_i"  shape="circle"];

  I1 -> I2;
}
```

2. Inside a `r chunk`, one calls `dot2tex` ([dot2tex](https://dot2tex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) to convert the `gv` file to a `LaTeX tikz` picture. Next, one compiles the `tex` file to `pdf` and crops it. In the end, one converts the cropped `pdf` figure to `svg` format (using `dvisvgm`, [dvisvgm](https://dvisvgm.de/)):

```
{r echo=F}
system("dot2tex --prog=neato --autosize -f tikz -t math sample.gv > sample.tex")
system("pdflatex sample.tex")
system("pdfcrop sample.pdf sample.pdf")
system("dvisvgm --pdf sample.pdf")
```

3. Finally, a `r chunk` to include the `svg` figure into the `rmarkdown` document:

```
{r echo=F, fig.cap="My caption.", out.width=500}
knitr::include_graphics("sample.svg")
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: This is really useful ... probably a way to build this into a knitr hook or such like; I may have a go later

Comment: I think so, @user20650. And since `add_mathjax` is buggy, my workaround could also be used to rewrite their `add_mathjax`. I filed a bug against `Diagrammer`, but nobody has answered... Many, many issues there are left without any reply...